# Pandas: replace all words in a row with a certain value except for words from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace, split

I have a dataframe as follows but larger:

```
df = {"text": ["it is two degrees warmer", "it is five degrees warmer today", "it was ten degrees warmer and not cooler", "it is ten degrees cooler", "it is too frosty today", "it is a bit icy and frosty today" ]}

allowed_list= ["cooler", "warmer", "frosty", "icy"]
```

I would like to replace all the words except for the words in the list with 'O', while keeping it comma separated like this:

```
 desired output:

 text
 0  O,O,O,O,warmer
 1  O,O,O,O,warmer,O
 2  O,O,O,O,warmer,O,O,cooler
 3  O,O,O,O,cooler
 4  O,O,O,frosty,O
 5  O,O,O,O,icy,O,frosty,O,
```

what I have done so far is to split the sting rows to list with `str.split(' ')` based on white space but not sure how to get rid of the words that are not in the list.

Comment: did you leave off a `pd.DataFrame` in your definition of `df`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension, and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) back setting `,` as a separator. Also by building a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) from `allowed_list` we'll have a faster lookup:

```
allowed_set= set(["cooler","warmer","frosty","icy"])
df['text'] = [','.join([w if w in allowed_set else 'O' for w in s.split()]) 
              for s in df['text']]
```

---

```
print(df)

                        text
0             O,O,O,O,warmer
1           O,O,O,O,warmer,O
2  O,O,O,O,warmer,O,O,cooler
3             O,O,O,O,cooler
4             O,O,O,frosty,O
5     O,O,O,O,icy,O,frosty,O
```